# Can area51 go in the list of related sites at the bottom of the page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51

I knew I'd signed up but had a brain fade moment and couldn't remember the name. I had to come here and browse likely looking questions until I found the name of the site!

A link on the bottom of the pages of the other sites in the family would be great.

Comment: This would also increase exposure to sites that are being suggested.

Answer (score 4):

And I see it's now there - thank you!

Comment: good job! =D  * applause *

Comment: It's gone now :o